# Bind to a static field in Windows 8 XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

How can I bind to a static field in Windows 8 XAML ? In WPF, we used to be able to do something like the following :

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static resources:Messages.LastName}"/>
```

But it appears that x:Static is no longer valid in Windows 8 XAML. Are there any good resources out there for those migrating from WPF to Windows 8 ?

Comment: Please be careful with your RTing.  [Windows 8 == Windows RT, but Windows RT != Windows Runtime](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152477/135887).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either refactor your code so that the property isn't static any more or create a proxy object that relays your static property changes. Either way you would end up with an instance of a class e.g. by having one defined in your resources and then you would bind like this:

```
Text="{Binding LastName, Source={StaticResource Messages}}"
```